# Redux-saga: how to pass string params with GET method

Tags: reactjs, parameters, get, redux-saga

I'm working with react/redux/redux-saga and I need to pass some params in this format "idUser=10&search="something".

With redux-saga I'm using classic try-catch like this:

```
try {
    const req = yield call(request, requestURL, {
      method: 'GET',
      body,
    });
    yield call(loadUsers);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('ERR', err);
  }
```

As I said body is equal to idUser=10&search="something", but from chrome console I notice no params were sent...I think BODY is not the right way for passing params with GET method in redux-saga but I can't find a way to do that...any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use:

```
const req = yield call(request, `${requestURL}?idUser=10&search=something`, {
   method: 'GET'
});
```